# Getting value using key Kotlin list

Tags: kotlin

I have following list

```
            val Costs = Data
            .groupBy { 
            it.Category
            }
            .map { (key, value) ->
                listOf(
                    key,
                    value.sumOf { it.CostInUsd.toBigDecimal() }
                )
            }
```

which outputs / has values;

```
[[Data A, 6.681491609], [Data B, 0.004615489], [Data C, 73.518534497], [, 0]]
```

I am trying the assign the value to a variable

```
var totalCost: BigDecimal = BigDecimal.ZERO
totalCost = Costs["Data A"]
println(totalCost)
```

I am getting the following error;
"Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Int was expected"

Comment: As a point of style, in Kotlin (like Java) it's usual for variables, properties, and other identifiers to start with a lower-case letter, with only classes (and constants and type parameters) starting with a capital. While this doesn't affect the meaning of your code, other people might find it easier to read if it followed those [Kotlin coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#naming-rules).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly that in your `map()` step you wanted to keep a `Map`, but transform its values, then you should use a `mapValues()` function instead:

```kotlin
val Costs = Data
    .groupBy {
        it.Category
    }
    .mapValues { (_, value) ->
        value.sumOf { it.CostInUsd.toBigDecimal() }
    }
```

Even better, you can sum costs while grouping. This way we avoid creating lists which we use only to calculate sums of them:

```kotlin
Data.groupingBy { it.Category }
    .fold(BigDecimal.ZERO) { acc, it -> acc + it.CostInUsd.toBigDecimal() }
```